# Rails API versioning and forum_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api, api-versioning

I try to add the `location` header to my versioned API.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `forum_url' for #<V1::ForumsController:0x00000004fabaa0>):app/controllers/v1/forums_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

How can I override the `render location: forum` helper to use `v1_forum_url`instead of `forum_url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply define a method forum_url in your controller:

```
def forum_url
  v1_forum_url
end
```

Or pass a custom method to location parameter.